# What is the reason to have two different Maps with the same addressing scheme?

Tags: scala, collections, hashmap

I'm looking at `scala.collection.mutable` maps and found out that there are 3 different kind of `Map`s with open addressing scheme:

1. [`OpenHashMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/OpenHashMap.html)
2. [`LongMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/LongMap.html)
3. [`AnyRefMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/AnyRefMap.html)

It is clear that in case of `Long`s we probably can take advantage of that and perform some optimizations. But the point of having `OpenHashMap` and `AnyRefMap` is not really clear.

As far as I know open addressing scheme optimized for `get`ing since we have less cache misses.

So for `Long`s we have `LongMap` for references `AnyRefMap`. Why would we ever use `OpenHashMap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there's no reason to use `OpenHashMap`. It has been deprecated in Scala 2.13: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/mutable/OpenHashMap.html